# disable all other elements after clicked once

Tags: jquery

I want to disable all buttons after any button has been clicked once.

```
jQuery('div').find('input[type="submit"]').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).one('click', function(e) {
    jQuery(this).css({
        'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .15)',
        'outline' : '0',
        '-webkit-box-shadow' : 'inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)',
        '-moz-box-shadow' : 'inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05)',
        'box-shadow' : 'inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)'
        }).unbind('click');


    });
})
```

here my current live snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/HyJvQ/3/

EDIT: SORRY FOR NOT MAKING CLEAR.

these element appear not just twice.. I want to disable one button in each pair after other button is click. 
updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/283g7/

Comment: Here is your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/HyJvQ/10/

Comment: his comment got it right and what I want really to come up.. though other answer are correct too but have different approach..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I want to work it out.. and I solve it via using .siblings()

```
$('body div').each(function() {
$(this).find('input[type="submit"]').each(function(){
    $(this).one('click', function(e){
                $(this).css({'border': 'red 1px solid'});
                $(this).siblings().unbind('click');
                })
})
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/283g7/2/

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong.

```
$('#someIdorButton').on('click',function(){
$('input:submit').prop('disabled',true); // or $('input').attr('disabled','disabled');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `prop()` to disable the buttons

```
jQuery('div').find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
```

try this

```
var buttons=jQuery('div').find('input[type="submit"]');
buttons.each(function () {
  jQuery(this).one('click', function (e) {
     jQuery(this).css({'border' : 'red 1px solid' }).unbind('click');
     buttons.prop('disabled',true);

  });
})
```

this will find all the button inside your `div` and disable it

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/HyJvQ/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var $buttons = $('div input[type="submit"]');

$buttons.click(function (e) {
    $(this).css({'border' : 'red 1px solid' });
    $buttons.off('click');
})
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HyJvQ/9/**